# sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID

Tags: java, smartcard, pkcs#11

I am new to SmartCard and need some help. I try to run a test program (see below), but keep getting this exception, `sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID`.

My system is `Windows 7 64-bit` and java version is `1.8.0_31`.

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    final StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(); 
    buff.append("name=").append("SmartCard").append("\n"); 
    buff.append("library=").append("C:\\Progra~1\\ActivIdentity\\ActivClient\\acpkcs211.dll").append("\n");
    buff.append("showInfo=true").append("\n"); 
    buff.append("slotListIndex=0").append("\n"); 

    final SunPKCS11 provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(buff.toString().getBytes())); 
    Security.addProvider(provider);  

    KeyStore.ProtectionParameter pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("######".toCharArray());  
    KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", provider, pp);
    KeyStore ks = builder.getKeyStore(); 
    ks.load(null, null); 
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore instantiation failed
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2.getKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at myTests.P11Test.main(P11Test.java:38)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: load failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:843)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_FindObjectsInit(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.findObjects(P11KeyStore.java:2658)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.mapLabels(P11KeyStore.java:2396)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:835)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID error indicates that one of the attributes passed (probably showInfo or slotListINdex) is not valid. Try removing them one by one and see if it fixes the error.